# Are questions asking to help with writing a music piece off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions asking to help the OP with a score that they're writing off-topic, for example:

Ideas for the Treble Clef line for this piece of music?

Because I could do with knowing, as I have several unfinished compositions lying around on my PC, and I could to with tips for some of them.

Comment: You can always ask in chat for someone to listen and give feedback, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything specific to a particular work is probably going to be off-topic since it won't be useful to others, and probably opinion based besides.

If you can generalize it to a question about how to achieve X, where X might be of interest to others, that would be okay.

Answer (score 4):

I'd really like to see more composition focused questions, but just asking for advice on a specific piece isn't really the best because:

- We prefer questions that will be useful for future users. While it will be very helpful for you in the short term, it won't be very applicable to anyone else.
- What anyone suggests is equally valid and so it won't be in the best form for a Q&A site and will be very opinionated.
- Just the general fact that someone else will be writing part of your piece for you which may carry its own issues.

Like Matthew said generalization is the key and for your example question a lot can be asked around it. If you can distill the generalities about your piece you can generate many on topic questions. There are already many questions on [harmonization including this one about specific scales](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6879/how-to-harmonize-uncommon-scales). Also you can about stylistic choices in a piece if that's what you're having trouble with [as seen in this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26819/how-to-write-a-ragtime-piano-piece). Questions like this should get you started in the right direction while being helpful to future users.

If you really want to ask about a specifc peice you can ask for [advice in our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) as similar questions have been asked there before.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would fall under the basic analysis option for close voting. It will be of little help to others and may clog up the front page and drive other more universally interesting questions away.